# Speech Synthesizer Pause Speaking returns true but doesn't pause text

Tags: swift, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

so I'm trying to get my speech synthesiser to pause, but for some reason, it's not pausing. I'm a beginner so I've been trying a few things but can't seem to figure out why. Would appreciate if someone can show me what went wrong.

The stop button seems to work fine

```swift
    @IBAction func speak(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if !speechSynthesizer.isSpeaking {
            let speechUtterence = AVSpeechUtterance(string: texts.text)
            speechUtterence.rate = rate // 0.0 - 1.0
            speechUtterence.pitchMultiplier = pitch // 0.5 - 2.0 (Default: 1.0)
            speechUtterence.volume = volume // 0.0 - 1.0 (Default: 1.0)

            speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterence)
        } else {
            speechSynthesizer.continueSpeaking()
        }
        animateActionButtonAppearance(true) //show Speak Button
    }

    @IBAction func pauseSpeech(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(speechSynthesizer.pauseSpeaking(at: .word))
        print("pause")

        animateActionButtonAppearance(false) //hide SpeakButton
    }

    @IBAction func stopSpeech(_ sender: UIButton) {
        speechSynthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)

        animateActionButtonAppearance(false) //hide SpeakButton
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it appears this is a typical beginner mistake where the sent event was assigned wrongly

[image]

The part I find interesting is, even though the stop button has the same problem, it appears to be working.

And this happened caused I duplicated my speak button without checking this page before assigning new targets for it. So that's a lesson learned.